# Is it possible to manage the tooltip in widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

[image]

As `Edittext` it is not the only one in the group widget. With `TextInputLayout` the hint didn't work. Tell me is there any way else to summon help?

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_account_tint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:theme="@style/EditText"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_selectcontact"
            android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number_contact_name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:theme="@style/EditText" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/et_account_button"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="@{presenter::onClick}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Do like this 



           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/til_account"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:hintEnabled="true" app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_account_tint"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:theme="@style/EditText"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />

                 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

               <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/til_account"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                     app:hintEnabled="true" 
                   app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint">
                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_account"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_selectcontact"                           android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number_contact_name"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:theme="@style/EditText" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/et_account_button"
                                android:layout_width="70dp"
                                android:layout_height="35dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:onClick="@{presenter::onClick}"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
```

Comment: Does not work, I need all the editView and TextView were at one point.

Comment: put these two like app:hintEnabled="true"
              app:hintAnimationEnabled="false" in all <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_amount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintEnabled="true"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextHint">
So?

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It is works, but need add the RelativeLayout